# Upgrade 1.6x or ditch Expression Engine

Tags: upgrade, codeigniter

I was recommended to post my question here as it might get better answers from current developers of EE. My original post is over on EllisLab:
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/234789/
You can post your reply here and I will be back.

In a nutshell, I came back to EE after a long hiatus. EE looks to offer more but yet, something doesn't seem right. With a HUGE project ahead of me, should I not bother to upgrade 1.6 and go with something new like PyroCMS (based on CI by moving to Lavarel) or ProcessWire (or ????).

Basically if you had a large project that would take month and months to complete and be ever evolving, is EE a good bet?

I don't think EE will disappear overnight but I have seen CMS systems slowly fade away.

thanks!
Carlos

Comment: This question is too subjective for Stack Exchange sorry. While we have a very active community here, we try to stay on topic and only answer specific questions based on facts and references, not generalized discussions (which don't fit this Q&A format are better suited for Twitter, Reddit etc). For more details, read the [FAQ](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if EE's going to fade away; I think that even now, it's difficult to find developers who can maintain the existing systems.

As to the "shag/marry/avoid" question: that all depends on way too many factors. There is no "one best CMS", there's "the CMS that's best for you." Only you can really answer that question, because only you know the project scope and outlines and your own skill level / comfort level with maintaining it / the budget of your client(s) and their needs.

Answer (score 1):

You are, of course, asking a rather subjective question.  One man's meat is another man's poison, etc.  Having said that, it would be interesting to get a dialog going on this subject, so I will start it.

I have been using EE since the early days as well, and have built quite a few sites using both 1.x and 2.x  My overall opinion of the technology and the company is that both are mediocre at best.  Doesn't really suck, but neither does it shine.  Having said that, I am not aware of anything that is so much better (for my needs) that I am ready to jump ship.  I am currently building a site using Craft, which looks to have real promise, but it is still early days.

The platform is reasonably stable, but seems way overpriced given it's capabilities and the lack of support, unless you want to pay an additional $49 a month!  There are many incredibly frustrating things that seem completely out of line for a $300 piece of software - absolutely crap WYSIWYG editor (for clients), horrid image management, hellish membership management, having to jump through hoops to create common SEO metadata, and amateurish documentation.  Most of the items on the complaint list can be addressed with add-ons,but that drives up the cost considerably and you can easily end up spending $500 to $600, plus incur the burden of dealing with multiple vendors for stuff that should be part of the base application.

I won't even get into the frustration with EE's confounding template parsing issues that will have you ripping out your hair and wasting huge amounts of time.

Addressing your question - if I were in your situation I would definitely look elsewhere.

Roi

Answer (score 1):

It's a subjective question but I think it's still good to have a little opinion in the forums. Naturally you'd get mostly biased answers here though. ;)

I've worked and still regularly work with many CMS' but in my honest opinion if I had a big project with a growing scope then I wouldn't even consider using another CMS. It can handle it all and allow you to architect it from day 1 to fit into your needs rather than you having to fit into the system.

EE is *very* mature and the community is thriving. Being commercial and having commercial addons is a huge advantage as it means that people's livelihoods are on the line in ensuring their addons and the system itself is always kept up to date and progressing forward. You don't get that with various other open source CMS'. Nor do you get the level of support that EE themselves offer along with that which you'll find here in the community. If you don't know the answer to something you can bet your bottom dollar someone else will and will be more than happy to offer suggestions.

I can't think of anything better to use knowing I'm working with a system that allows me to do virtually anything in the way **I** want to do it whilst having a willing community of people there to help out when I have a question or get stuck. In addition to official support for EE with a guaranteed response time and commercial addons guaranteeing a high level of quality and support you can go into each project fearless! :)

(Plus, for only $50 to upgrade what's the lose??)